# SQL server management studio Express

Tags: sql, sql-server

I authenicate to my SQL Server instance by logging in with a Windows account via SQL Server Management Studio.  I want to change this to a SQL server login.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean simply changing the current connection?

Comment: please read what you just wrote its very unclear what you want to do...

Comment: sory sory!! i want to connect to SQL by server authentication.. and not by windows authentication .. how can i do tht??

Answer (score 2):

The default installation of SQL Server only supports Windows Authentication.

If you want to use SQL authentication (e.g. "sa" for the superuser), you need to:

1. Using SQL Server Management Studio, connect to the server. Use Windows Authentication for now.
2. Right-click on the server instance you want to modify. This is usually the root item in the tree in the left-hand panel.
3. Select Properties from the context menu.
4. In the Server Properties window, select Security from the left-hand panel.
5. Under Server Authentication, change the radio button from "Windows Authentication mode" (the default), to "SQL Server and Windows Authentiation mode".

Now you can create SQL server logins which you can use to connect to the server.

Comment: Remember to restart the SQL Server process for the change to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

When you first open Management Studio it asks you what credentials you wish to use to login.

For an actively connected session you need to change the current connection using the button on the tool bar (normally top left) which will pop up the login dialogue again.

Clearly this will depend on you having some SQL Server logins already defined on the server with appropriate permissions specified.